# How to apply a logo image on an imported 3ds mesh

Tags: image, three.js, mesh, 3ds

I'm quite new to Three.js and what I want to achieve is a model previewer before phisically print over a piece of wood.
So, I managed to import a 3ds model in my system, applied a wood material and now here's where I'm stuck: how can I apply an image on my imported mesh?

I've tried to create a texture material but I'm not able to understand how it is applied and what size / position should have the logo to be presented only on the frontal face of the object

Please consider I'm new to three.js, so come code / detailed hint would be very appreciated! ;)

Comment: look at UV mapping in 3dsmax. if you're model has a texture and UV coordinates already set you should be able to simply start playing with the texture directly. e.g. https://threejs.org/examples/?q=3ds#webgl_loader_3ds > https://threejs.org/examples/models/3ds/portalgun/textures/color.jpg > https://threejs.org/examples/models/3ds/portalgun/textures/normal.jpg

Comment: Unfortunately I read an external 3ds file.
Plus it's a "parametric" procedure, so I'm searching for a method that could be applied everytime, no matter the object I'm opening...

Comment: If the model is generated in a 3D editor (like 3dsmax), parametrically or not, whoever is responsible for generating the object is responsible for generating the UV mapping of the model so you can texture it. You can of course create the 3D mesh in three.js directly, dictate your own UV coordinates and even add a few sliders for live tweaking (here are a couple of *very old* examples http://lifesine.eu/labs/r61/diamond/d1.html, http://lifesine.eu/labs/r61/diamond/d4.html)